# Font of all headings in a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to retrieve the font name and size of all the headings from a word document. Any idea how to get it?

Comment: Do you mean headings as in "Headers" as in Headers/Footers or Headings like Heading1, Heading2, Heading3?  Are you wanting to make an array of these and then reuse them? Or do you just want a report of the fonts/sizes for the document? Are you wanting to reuse this vba for various documents where you won't have any control of the document or just ones that you have on your machine, but you have a lot them?

Comment: I want the Headings like Heading1, Heading2. I want to retrieve them for reporting and if possible to compare against a standard format for headings.

Comment: Hrm -- that makes it trickier. The actual text in the document might easily override the default header format. Are you looking for what the default Header1 font and size should be, or what they actually look like in a particular document?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that many users will set a their headers manually, often without regards to the "Headings" menu. So I may create a line that is 16pt Verdana, but the "node" is set to body, and I never notice. Is that something you're needing to worry about?

Comment: Ya dats the problem actually. The Fonts found as below and in actual doc are differnt       
 Set rng = docOutline.Content
    astrHeadings = _
     docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
      strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
      intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))
      strFont = rng.Font.Name

        rng.InsertAfter strText & intLevel
        rng.InsertAfter strFont & vbNewLine
        rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next intItem
End Sub

Comment: Please excuse me for the bad for mat above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure will be something like below:

```vb
Public Sub ShowFontAndSize()
    Dim singleLine As Paragraph
    Dim lineText As String

    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
     Debug.Print singleLine.Range.Font.Name
     Debug.Print singleLine.Range.Font.Size
    Next singleLine
End Sub
```

The catch will be that this won't sense if there are different fonts and sizes on the same line. If that's a possibility, you will need to add another loop with `For Each singleCharacter In singleLine.Range.Characters` inside of the paragraphs loop.

Edit: A trickier problem is what to do with this data once you've collected it. Building up an array seems like the natural fit, but VBA arrays are borderline useless, since basic methods like .append() require you to redim the whole array. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm for more info if you would like to go down that road.

Comment: Is there a similar loop that can simply return all fonts and font size pairs used in the document without looping through each character? I would think that this meta-info would be stored in such a way that you could retrieve it without going letter by letter. If it can be returned in that way, maybe he could use a certain amount of guessing that the smallest font-size is not a header and thus all others ARE headers? A big guess, I know, but a fairly safe one in most situations.

Comment: There is, and you touched on it in your answer earlier. But, it's unfortunately useless in any typical working environment. Word tries to store all the fonts/sizes/etc using the HeadingStyles collection, but only the most meticulous users use that feature consistently. Everyone else uses overrides, since it's easier to override than to use the headers, especially in Word 2003 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution is to open the document in Word and access the object model. This is traditionally done using VBA, but you can also use .NET (e.g. C# og VB.NET) by using VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office). Personally I find C#/VB.NET much better languages than VBA.

Once you have access to the object model you will have to enumerate paragraphs in the document. When you find a heading (perhaps defined by the style) you will have to figure out the formatting of the heading.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from a brief skim of the [MSDN page on "HeadingStyles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221972%28office.11%29.aspx):

```
MsgBox ActiveDocument.HeadingStyles(1).Style
```